# Handling Radio Button in ListView With Data From a Server

Tags: android, listview

Hello guys how are you ? 
I have been trying to use ListView with Radio Buttons. But, I am having some problems with the Radio Button Handling. 
Anyways, my application is supposed to deal with data from Mysql server. The Data which is retrieved from the server as the followings :

a 1

b 0

c 1

d 1

e 0

So, you can see that I only have two columns column One is a name and Column Two is a number ( This number can be only 1 or 0 nothing more)
So, I have created my shape to handle the two columns as TEXT's. I had no problem. But, When I tried to use Radio Buttons. I have started to have issued.
Bellow are my layout's and my classes.

Shape Layout :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/CHOOSING_ABSENCE">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/present"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/absence"/>

          </RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:id="@+id/Student_name"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

I don't think I have a problem in here.

The second class is my Custom class:

```
 public class ListViewStudentEditAbsence {
private  String StudentName ;
private String StudentID ;
private int Absence  ;

public ListViewStudentEditAbsence(String StudentName, String  StudentID, String Absence )
{
    this.StudentName = StudentName ;
    this.StudentID = StudentID;
    if(Absence == "0")
        this.Absence = 0  ;
    else
        this.Absence = 1  ;

}


public int getAbsence() {
    return Absence;
}

public void setAbsence(int absence) {
    Absence = absence;
}

public String getStudentID() {
    return StudentID;
}

public void setStudentID(String studentID) {
    StudentID = studentID;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return StudentName;
}


public void setStudentName(String studentName)
{
    StudentName = studentName;
}
}
```

My Adapter is as the followings :

```
 public class ListViewStudentEditAbsenceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListViewStudentEditAbsence>
  {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ListViewStudentEditAbsence> mData;


public ListViewStudentEditAbsenceAdapter (Context mContext, ArrayList<ListViewStudentEditAbsence> mData) {
    super(mContext, R.layout.student_name_editing, mData);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = new ArrayList<ListViewStudentEditAbsence>();
    this.mData.addAll(mData);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.student_name_editing, null);
    }
    TextView Name  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Student_name);
    Name.setText(mData.get(position).getStudentName());
/*
    RadioGroup Absence  = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CHOOSING_ABSENCE);
    Absence.setText(mData.get(position).getAbsence());
  */
    return convertView;
}
 }
```

As you can see I committed handling the radio button because I couldn't solve this issue.

I hope you can help

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: The radio Group has two radio Buttons. One is for 0 and the other is for 1. How can I do that depending on the retrieved data ? Indeed, when I run the application, the radio group doesn't focus on either of the radio buttons

Comment: you want radio button to be checked when value is 1 & unchecked when value is 0 ? is it what you want ?

Comment: No, I want radio button One to be checked when the data is 1. And I want button Two to be checked when the data is 0. Got that ?

Comment: why not directly setting RadioButtons why Radio Group ?

Comment: what is the need of Radio Group there ?

Comment: Because the user is supposed to use only one Option. If you have a better way to do so, I will be very glad

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90887/discussion-between-ama989-and-syed-nazar-muhammad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 if(Absence == "0")
    this.Absence = 0  ;
else
    this.Absence = 1  ;
```

to

```
 if(Absence.equals("0"))
    this.Absence = 0  ;
else
    this.Absence = 1  ;
```

and

```
 RadioGroup Absence  = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CHOOSING_ABSENCE);
Absence.setText(mData.get(position).getAbsence());
```

to

```
 RadioGroup Absence  = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CHOOSING_ABSENCE);
if((mData.get(position).getAbsence() == 1))
Absence.check(R.id.present);
else
Absence.check(R.id.absence);
```

Comment: At this point, we have read the data. What If I want to write Data using the same radio Buttons. Did you get my question ?

Comment: yes  you can use RadioButton rb = findViewById(R.id.present);  and then create condition if(rb.ischecked())  somevariable =  somevalue else // some other code

Comment: I am going to give it  a try. Thank You again

Comment: for(int i=0;i<countryList.size();i++) {
                    country = countryList.get(i);
                    if (country.equals(1)) {
                        Absence[i] = 1 + "";
                    } else {
                        Absence[i] = 0 + "";
                    }
But whenever there is a change. I can't save the status